# DBeaver CSV import UTF-8 no umlaute possible

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am trying to import data from a **CSV** file in my `PostgreSQL` database using `DBeaver`.

I set the *charset* to `UTF-8` (for the database itself and the imported **CSV**).

Here is what the Import looks like..

[image]

After the import, all the umlaute, for example an `ä` or an `ö` get displayed as a `?`.

[image]

When I edit the name afterwards, it somehow works...

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Make sure the file is really UTF-8. It probably isn't.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! I saved it as CSV and not as CSV with UTF8 formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your error is not in the DBeaver configuration, I would recommend you check with which UTF-8 configuration you are saving the CVS from the sheet or Excel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was generated by using Mac OS, for this I changed the encoding to MacRoman, and this worked perfectly.